# Issue FORM POST Request From PHP using HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: php, post, basic-authentication

I hope this is a relatively straight forward thing to do, and that my google skills have simply failed me on this occasion. I have a BASIC authentication protected resource which I want to have PHP perform a POST HTTP request against.

I have tried injecting **Authentication: Basic (encrypted u/p data)** into the headers which didn't appear to work - so I wonder, can the powers of *Greyskull* i mean StackOverflow provide any guidance.

```
$req .= "&cmd=_initiate_query";
$header = "POST /someendpoint HTTP/1.1\r\n".
        "Host:example.com\n".
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
        "User-Agent: PHP-Code\r\n".
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n".
        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://example.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $result .= fgets ($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose ($fp);
}
```

Comment: have you tried (or have access) to use curl for this ?

Comment: Good point, something I should have stated. I am trying to minimise (if not negate) the requirement for modifications to php.ini.
I have already had to activate the OpenSSL extension to do SSL..which is a pain, and CURL may be an option but I would rather explore all avenues without CURL first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
$header = "POST /someendpoint HTTP/1.1\r\n".
        "Host:example.com\n".
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
        "User-Agent: PHP-Code\r\n".
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n".
        "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($username.':'.$password)."\r\n".
        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

Should work - are you sure it is a Basic authentication system? It may be worth watching the raw header data using something like [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to ensure it is an authentication (and you'll be then able to copy the authorization string as well!).

Comment: Thanks Richy, that's what I had - I wonder if I wrote it in British English (i.e. Authorisation) which would obviously not work. Will investigate this approach further.

Comment: Fingers crossed: as a Brit, I've made the Authorisation/Authorization slip a few times myself.

I have also known some authentication sites check the HTTP_REFERER (sic) header for "additional authentication" along with also using cookies (yep, damn complex to automate the logins!). CharlesProxy (or Microsoft's Fiddler) will let you see what your browser is sending and allow you to replicate that in code.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a function I use to perform POST requests.  Hopefully it can do what you want:

```
function http_post($server, $port, $url, $vars) {

// get urlencoded vesion of $vars array 
$urlencoded = ""; 

foreach ($vars as $Index => $Value) 
    $urlencoded .= urlencode($Index ) . "=" . urlencode($Value) . "&"; 

$urlencoded = substr($urlencoded,0,-1);  

$headers = "POST $url HTTP/1.0\r\n" 
. "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" 
. "Content-Length: ". strlen($urlencoded) . "\r\n\r\n"; 

$fp = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10); 
if (!$fp) return "ERROR: fsockopen failed.\r\nError no: $errno - $errstr"; 

fputs($fp, $headers); 
fputs($fp, $urlencoded); 

$ret = ""; 
while (!feof($fp)) $ret .= fgets($fp, 1024); 

fclose($fp); 
return $ret; }
```

And here's an example of me using it to forward on the POST variables to an API

```
$response = http_post("www.nochex.com", 80, "/nochex.dll/apc/apc", $_POST);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that appears to be pretty much what I have and does not deal with the matter of the question - HTTP Basic authentication.