# POST request with Basic Authentication from Appengine in PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, post

How to send a POST request with Basic Authentication from Appengine in PHP? 
I already checked [Issue FORM POST Request From PHP using HTTP Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198756/issue-form-post-request-from-php-using-http-basic-authentication) but solution is not working in Appengine environment.

Please suggest any workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution you posted uses sockets, which will only work if you have billing enabled (See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/).

Alternatively, you could use file_get_contents with the "Authorization" header set in the stream context (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/), e.g.

```
$context =
array("http"=>
  array(
    "method" => "post",
    "header" => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username.':'.$password) . "\r\n",
    "content" => $data
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$result = file_get_contents(url, false, $context);
```

Comment: Getting following error: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request , plain text sent to https

Comment: Specifically I want to send request like mentioned here http://dev.cloudup.com/#items-create-url

Comment: Yes, it works for HTTPS as well. Based on Cloudup's documentation, the request body must be either application/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Assuming you have set $data correctly, you'll also need to set the content-type header accordingly.

Comment: You're missing a \r after your "Host" header, and an extra pair or \r\n at the end. Also note that the urlfetch service will set standard headers like Host, Content-Length etc. for you automatically: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/#PHP_Request_headers