# 400 Bad request error on Sending POST request to Cloudup from Google Appengine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, post

I am using the following code in PHP, hosted with Google AppEngine to save a file via creating a URL item through POST request to Cloudup.com

```
<?php
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $req = array('url' => 'http://www.example.com/files/test.pdf');
    $req= http_build_query($req);
    $header = "POST /items/url HTTPS/1.1\r\n".
        "Host: cloudup.com\n".
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
        "User-Agent: PHP-Code\r\n".
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n".
        "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($username.':'.$password)."\r\n".
        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    $result = '';

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.cloudup.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR
        echo 'error';
    } else {
        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $result .= fgets ($fp);
            var_dump($result);
        }
        fclose ($fp);
    }
?>
```

All requests must be made over HTTPS, and are otherwise rejected. Therefore I am using following Handler in app.yaml:

```
- url: /home
  script: main.php
  secure: always
```

To use the sockets I have enabled the billing.

Specification for Cloudup URL item Post request is here: http://dev.cloudup.com/#items-create-url

Problem: getting 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'. Please provide any solution.

Comment: See my comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666878/post-request-with-basic-authentication-from-appengine-in-php/21669067